# RuntimeError during twinx() in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I get the following error while doing plt.twinx()

```
RuntimeError: Locator attempting to generate 1993 ticks from 0.075257498916 to 199.95917462: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS
```

The corresponding code is :

```
x1 = np.ones(100)*np.median(a)
y1 = np.linspace(1,500,100)
position_x = (np.around(np.linspace(0.0, np.max(a),6),2)).astype(int)

def tick_function(x):
    """Specify tick format"""
    return ["%2.f" % i for i in x]

def func(x):
    """This can be anything you like"""
    funcx=np.log10(1.0+x)
    return funcx


fig=plt.figure(figsize=(7,6),dpi=100)
plt.hist(log_z, bins=40, histtype='step')
y_hist = plt.twiny()
y_hist.set_yticks(func(position_x))
y_hist.set_yticklabels(tick_function(position_x))
y_hist.set_ylabel('z')
plt.show()
```

I am unable to figure out why this is happening. Any suggestion on the source of this error and to fix it is appreciated.
P.S. I am using Python 2.7, and matplotlib version 2.2.4.

Comment: Is `a` 1d or 2d?  What is `np.max(a)`?

Comment: @JohanC a is a 1D array. The value of max(a) is 6.

Comment: Do you have a possibility to upgrade to Python 3 and use a less antiquated matplotlib?

Comment: I did : `def tick_function(X):`
    `V = 10**X - 1.`
    `return ["%i" % z for z in V]` and `Y = np.linspace(1,7,7)`
`new_tick_locations = np.log10(Y)`
`ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())`
`ax2.set_xticks(new_tick_locations)`
`ax2.set_xticklabels(tick_function(new_tick_locations))` That did the trick (in Python 2.7)

Comment: @AMC: You are encouraged to post and accept [answers to your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).